# Django: Serialize to JSON a dictionary with items that can include querysets

Tags: python, json, django

I'm sending a JSON object (component_list is a QuerySet) in this way:

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', component_list)
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

However I want to fill more information like this:

```
data = {}
data['ok'] = True
data['component_list'] = serializers.serialize('json', component_list)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

But it doesn't work since serializers.serialize('json', component_list) is already a json structure and I'm trying to make it json again with json.dumps.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Check if it works. Build your dictionary first like this `data['component_list'] = component_list` and then dump the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found myself a solution. I think I can help other people with that.

I created my own encoder class to format the querysets as much as I want.

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """ json.JSONEncoder extension: handle querysets """
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, QuerySet) or isinstance(obj, RawQuerySet):
            return serializers.serialize('python', obj, ensure_ascii=False)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

then, in my view function:

```
data['ok'] = True
data['component_list'] = component_list
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, cls=MyEncoder),  content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I suggest using `django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder` instead of the python library. It will allow the encoding of datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Did this work?

```
data = {}
data['ok'] = True
data['component_list'] = component_list
data = serializers.serialize('json', data) # or json.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Nop. AttributeError at /components/filter_results/
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: I tried with json.dumps as well but it has problems with RawQuerySet (component_list is a RawQuerySet)

Comment: Oh then `queryset.values()` may solve your problem :)

Comment: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: ohk.. maybe `[i.__dict__ for i in queryset]`

Answer (score 0):

Improving this by using DjangoJSONEncoder, as @tburette suggested...

```
class MyJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, QuerySet) or isinstance(obj, RawQuerySet):
            return serializers.serialize('python', obj, ensure_ascii=False, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
        return super().default(obj)
```

I call this like:

```
from common.helpers import MyJSONEncoder

x = Part.objects.filter(description__icontains=q)[:10].only('part_code','description')
y = Part.objects.filter(description__icontains=q).count()
data = {'x': x, 'y': y} 
return JsonResponse(data, encoder=MyJSONEncoder)
```