# Raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") when trying to update the data in a div with ajax

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I got this Exception for, what I understood, passing a dictionary with objects through json:

```
    Internal Server Error: /dashboard/ajax/reload_data/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/micael/Documents/MySite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages /django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
File "/home/micael/Documents/MySite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/micael/Documents/MySite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/micael/Documents/djangoDashboard/dashboard/views.py", line 34, in reload_data
    data = json.dumps(content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <QuerySet [{u'nome_cliente': u'ABBBBA'}, {u'nome_cliente': u'MediaPrime'}, {u'nome_cliente': u'ITeCons'}, {u'nome_cliente': u'ABA'}, {u'nome_cliente': u'ABBA'}, {u'nome_cliente': u'SELT'}]> is not JSON serializable
[16/May/2018 17:15:57] "GET /dashboard/ajax/reload_data/ HTTP/1.1" 500 21406
```

**The ajax view:**

```
def reload_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        b = Jobs.objects.order_by('end_time').reverse()[:10]
        u = Update.objects.values('nome_cliente').distinct()
        content = {"backup_info": b, "update_info": u}
        x = Cliente.objects.all()
        for x in Cliente.objects.all():
            now = time.time()
            minTime = now - 86400 #last_28h
            n_jobs_last_24h = Jobs.objects.filter(id_cliente_id=x.id_cliente, insert_time__range=(minTime, now)).count()
            if n_jobs_last_24h < x.n_jobs:
                 #faltam jobs
                messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Cliente %s com menos %s jobs!' % (x.identificador, (x.n_jobs - n_jobs_last_24h)))

        data = json.dumps(content)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

**The template code:**

```
                <div id ="update">
                <div id="dash1div">
                    <a href="">
                        <strong>Updates</strong>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <ul>
                {% for update_info in update_info %}
                    <li>
                        <a id = "{{update_info.nome_cliente}}" href="/dashboard/ListUpdate/{{update_info.nome_cliente}}/">{{update_info.nome_cliente}}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**The Ajax Code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
    console.log('am i called');   
    $.ajax({
    url: '/dashboard/ajax/reload_data/',
    success: function (data){
          response_json = JSON.parse(data)
          $('body').html(response_json.html_data);
       }
    });
   },1000)
</script>
```

I found some solutions but I can't adapt them to my code! Can you help me? And is this the best solution to refresh the div over the time?

**Thank you for helping!**

Comment: The error here says that your view has `data = json.dumps([p.__dict__ for p in content])` instead of `data = json.dumps(content)`.

Comment: Furthermore the title shows a different error as well.

Comment: i already edited it!! ty, and yah i changed my code trying some solutions and that was a exception when using that solution but i'ts not suitable for python 2

Comment: well there is nothing wrong with trying to fix it yourself :) but please ensure (i.e. next time) that the code and errors, etc. are all in harmony.

Comment: @Micolhe: the problem is that your querysets are no Vanilla python objects, hence the JSON encoder does not know how to convert them to JSON. You will need to help Python with this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem any standart way to do it? if i convert dictionary in a list will it be fix?

Comment: "if i convert dictionary in a list will it be fix". No, because JSON can handle `dict`. What it can't handle is the `Queryset`s inside the `dict`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON encoding is supported for the following native python types out of the box

```
Supports the following objects and types by default:

+-------------------+---------------+
| Python            | JSON          |
+===================+===============+
| dict              | object        |
+-------------------+---------------+
| list, tuple       | array         |
+-------------------+---------------+
| str, unicode      | string        |
+-------------------+---------------+
| int, long, float  | number        |
+-------------------+---------------+
| True              | true          |
+-------------------+---------------+
| False             | false         |
+-------------------+---------------+
| None              | null          |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

So if you do `json.dumps(1)` -> it will work because this is supported by default.

Now your variable `content` is a python dictionary; which clearly is something you can JSON Serializer out of the box; if (and this is a big if) all the contents of the dictionary are also native types that can be serialized.

However, the contents of `content` are a Django `Queryset`, which is not natively JSON Serializeable.

You can however convert the queryset into all native python types using [django's serializer classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/), but that works well if you were only returning one queryset.

Since you are returning a dictionary, whose values are themselves querysets, I'd recommend you look at [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) or [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If you want to keep things simple; here's a great workaround, where you define a custom encoder that uses Django's serializer classes for Querysets, and the builtin one for other data types:
[Django: Serialize to JSON a dictionary with items that can include querysets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231111/django-serialize-to-json-a-dictionary-with-items-that-can-include-querysets)

Comment: I'm using Django Rest Framework in this particular case, because i think its the best solution and the most flexible toolkit... recomend it ;) ty for the answer!! :D